# Is there a way to disable the compatibility checker in Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a code to autosave in a new folder when I press a button; the code is working fine but the compatability checker comes up prior to allowing the save. Is there a way to disable this compatability checker so that the people using the autosave button do not get confused?

Here is my code:

```
Sub FILESAVE()

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="H:\Digital Production Control and Tally Sheet Library\ " & Range("'Production Control Sheet'!B2") & _
        Format(Now(), " mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm AMPM"), FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="kpqual", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True, CreateBackup:=False


End Sub
```

It works wonders, but I just don't know how to disable the compatability checker for issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
Sub FILESAVE()
        ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132972(v=office.14).aspx
        '51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsx)
        '52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsm)
        '50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)
        '56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls)
        ' See more info on http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="H:\Digital Production Control and Tally Sheet Library\ " & Range("'Production Control Sheet'!B2") & _
        Format(Now(), " mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm AMPM"), FileFormat:=52, Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="kpqual", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True, CreateBackup:=False    
End Sub
```